# Error: main.lua:22: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to get some 0 and 1 inside a multidimensional table but I can't get it to work. I've searched through a lot of posts but I couldn't find a way of solving it. This is the code:

```
    generatedTerrain={
{0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0}
}
x=0
y=0

    function mapGen()
        for y=1,67 do
            generatedTerrain[y]={}
            for x=1,89 do
                generatedTerrain[x][y] = math.random(0,1) --This doesn't work
            end
        end
    end
mapGen()
end
```

Comment: By the way, you neither need to initialize generatedTerrain in this detail (it'd suffice to initialize as empty table {}), nor x and y. In fact, you are causing Lua to create x and y as global values when local values (as the for loop would create implicitly) would suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've inverted the x and y indices in your table, so you've created 67 empty tables inside it, but in the next loop you're trying to access from 1 to 89

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get the table 67x89. But I never used the multidimensional tables before...

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel said, you need to change the order of `x` and `y` indices when you store/access elements. This should work:

```
local generatedTerrain={}
function mapGen()
  for y=1,67 do
    generatedTerrain[y]={}
    for x=1,89 do
      generatedTerrain[y][x] = math.random(0,1) --<-- changed order or x,y
    end
  end
end
mapGen()
```